# как-то странно работает pip install: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2016. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\Евгений>pip install pefile
Collecting pefile
  Downloading pefile-2016.3.28.tar.gz (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 497kB/s
Collecting future (from pefile)
  Using cached future-0.16.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: future, pefile
  Running setup.py install for future ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 69: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 69: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 729, in cleanup_files
    req.remove_temporary_source()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 977, in remove_temporary_source
    rmtree(self.source_dir)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\B7E3~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-vvhhdeg1\\future'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\build.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\build.py", line 42, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.name)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\евгений\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\B7E3~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-vvhhdeg1\\future'

C:\Users\Евгений>
```

И это всегда так происходит даже если ты перезагрузил компьютер.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать то, что описано здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651372/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-python/651653#651653

Comment: @hedgehogues не у меня win а не линукс

Comment: Это из-за русских букв в пути, в данном случае ваше имя :)

Comment: похоже на проблему с pip (несколько проблем с кодировкой консоли, дочерних процессов, изменений как это в Питон 3.6 + несколько хаков, чтобы отдельные issues закрыть). Попробуйте обновить pip. Или потестируйте ascii-only пути.¶ Помогает переменную окружения установить? https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251#issuecomment-296997516

Comment: связанный вопрос [UnicodeDecodeError при pip-установке библиотеки geopandas на Python 3.6 на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758039/23044)

Comment: версия интерпретатора не совпадает с пакетом который вы устанавливаете , решение обновить PIP pip install -U