# Установить selenium webdriver chromedriver на linux, используя python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я на стадии настройки Selenium на Ubuntu. Хочу использовать python 3.5 и chrome browser. Я установила pip3 и python 3.5. Скачала selenium и chromedriver через терминал и pip3. Сейчас я ничего не могу запустить, потому что получаю ошибку при загрузке webdriver:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полагаю, проблема в версии pip. Похоже, используется pip вместо pip3 - но как заставить работать pip3?

Comment: Вам принципиально работать под python3? Что насчёт Python2?

Comment: Питон == проблемы. Переходите на Руби.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была не в pip и не в версиях питона, а в том что на моей ubuntu стоял хром не последней версии. А хромдрайвер я естесственно скачала последний. Только после апдейта хрома все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что у Вас просто не установлен `pip3`. Для того, чтобы его установить, нужно сделать `apt-get`. Предварительно, право, обновите его:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Далее можете ставить `pip3`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Если же вдруг окажется, что pip3 поставлен, то в любом случае, попробуйте его переустановить:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
```

Что касается `pip` и `pip3`. Первый объект, как правило относится к `python2.7`. Второй -- к `python3.5`. Часто бывает так, что при установке версии 2.7 `pip` устанавливается сразу. С `pip3` обычно больше косяков. Его нужно подтянуть `apt-get`, как я указал выше. Но нужно понимать, что по неведомым мне причинам при установке пакетов для 3 версии, проблем возникает гораздо больше, чем при работе со 2 версией.

Что касается `selenium` и `webDriver`, то устанавливать Вам нужно именно `selenium`. По крайней мере, на 2 питоне вместе с ним в комплекте идёт и webdriver для большого кол-ва браузеров. Сделать это можно, очевидно, так:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

После проделанных операций, по идее, всё будет более или менее ставиться из PyCharm, в котором Вы работаете.

Comment: не стоит на Ubuntu выполнять `sudo pip* install` вообще. Так можно сломать системные утилиты, использующие Питон. В системные области, следует ставить используя системный же менеджер пакетов. К примеру, `sudo apt-get install python3-selenium`

Comment: @jfs Первый раз о таком слышу. Хорошо, возьму на заметку.

Comment: @jfs по-вашему pip -- это плохая вещь?

Comment: если не ясно почему не следует `sudo pip` на Ubuntu делать (если вы твёрдо не знаете все последствия), то задайте отдельный вопрос -- мне кажется и другим полезно может быть.

Comment: @jfs http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651860/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-sudo-pip

Comment: извините (спасибо за советы) но у меня не получается сделать: sudo apt-get uninstall python3-pip. Выводит:
E: Invalid operation uninstall

Comment: @Anastaia remove