# UnicodeDecodeError при pip-установке библиотеки geopandas на Python 3.6 на Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

При установке библиотеки geopandas в Pycharm выдает ошибку:

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled3>pip install geopandas
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting shapely (from geopandas)
  Using cached Shapely-1.6.3.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 24: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

После попытки:

```
 python -m pip install -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
```

Стало так:

```
 C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled3>pip install geopandas
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyproj in 
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from geopandas) (1.9.5.1)
Collecting descartes (from geopandas)
  Using cached descartes-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting shapely (from geopandas)
  Using cached Shapely-1.6.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aj00gsti\shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install\aj00gsti\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aj00gsti\shapely\
```

Как это дело исправить?
Попробовал chcp . Выводит:

```
Текущая кодовая страница: 866
```

Команда `py -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"` выводит:

```
utf-8
```

Команда `pip --version` выводит:

```
pip 10.0.0.dev0 from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: 1) PyCharm -- IDE, она не содержит библиотеки, установка идет в папку питона 2) Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой 3) как устанавливаете библиотеку? через pip install или через диалог PyCharm? 4) Нет ли русских букв в путях к питону? 5) Имя компьютера имеет русские буквы?

Comment: Полный стек с ошибкой здесь http://prntscr.com/hna3ts

Comment: Зачем ссылка на внешний ресурс, если можно к самому вопросу приложить? Нажмите на кнопку `править` и добавьте туда стек. Причем не нужно скриншотом, если есть возможность выделить и скопировать, то приложите текстом, т.к. текст в картинке не индексируется, а значит вопрос потеряет важность и его не смогут найти люди с аналогичной проблемой

Answer (score 2):

Это [баг в `pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4903). Он [уже исправлен](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4486/files) (вместо исключения, [кракозябры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/) можете получить, если кодировка не та).

Если нет возможности [обновиться](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110#issuecomment-342373982) до исправленной версии pip, можно [workaround](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110) попробовать: `chcp 866` (по умолчанию OEM кодировка на русской Windows).

Comment: Прошу прощения за малограммность. Судя по https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/8a101321f6aaa24dd796241221f81a92bf116e9f , мне надо файлы окорректировать ?

Comment: @Rashid-s нет. При запуске в консоли команды pip install, убедитесь что кодировка по умолчанию используется. chcp что выводит?

Comment: У меня такой кодировки кажется нету. Если я там смотрю где надо http://prntscr.com/hnrmar

Comment: А вот я сейчас сделал как здесь указано: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110#issuecomment-342373982



     python -m pip install -Uhttps://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip

Comment: И у меня теперь такая ошибка:



     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvqbj78c\shapely\

Comment: *"кодировки нету"* Откройте Windows консоль (cmd). Запустите chcp. Скопируйте результат как текст сюда. Если не ясно как эти шаги выполнить, задайте отдельный вопрос.¶ Если у вас `pip install -U .../pip/archive/master.zip` не работает, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вот что в командной строке: Текущая кодовая страница: 866

Comment: @Rashid-s отлично. Теперь в той же консоли, где вы chcp запускали, выполните `pip install geopandas`

Comment: то же самое:




     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkfie0j2\shapely\

Comment: @Rashid-s: обновите ваш вопрос и добавьте содержимое консоли с командами `chcp, pip --version, pip install ..`. Можно ещё `py -mpip` попробовать. Что `py -с "import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())"` показывает? Ещё: `py -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"`

Comment: выполнил обновление вопроса

Comment: @Rashid-s: Отсутствие `geos_c.dll` это уже другая ошибка, не имеет отношения к проблеме с кодировкой (сообщение на русском языке вывелось без ошибки). Выполните `py -mpip install shapely` (должны получить ошибку с `geos_c.dll`). В отдельный вопрос добавьте вывод этой команды (затем попробуйте wheel для вашей системы скачать https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely либо через conda устанавливайте (не смешивайте эти способы для разных библиотек) и если получится установить, то как свой ответ добавьте — [это явно приветствуется](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self)