# pip install выдает ошибки. Как побороть ошибку 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 18: invalid continuation byte?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, unicode, pip

Устанавливаю Flask с помощью команды pip install flask и появляется следующие сообщения об ошибках. Как это побороть?

> `Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py",
>   line 73, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 18: invalid
>   continuation byte`
>
> `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`
>
> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in mai n
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 342, i n run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py",
>   line 784, in ins tall
>       **kwargs   File "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
>   line 878, in  install
>       spinner=spinner,   File "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py",
>   line 676, in call_subprocess
>       line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())   File "c:\users\генка\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py",
>   line 75, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode('utf_8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 18: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: использую PyCharm

Comment: связанный вопрос [UnicodeDecodeError при pip-установке библиотеки geopandas на Python 3.6 на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758039/23044)