# Не могу установить Twisted для Scrapy. Ошибка кодировки

Tags: python, utf-8, pip, scrapy, twisted

Попытался установить Scrapy. Ввёл pip install scrapy, как в офф. доке. Вылетела ошибка. Снизу лог консоли. Понимаю, что проблема в кодировке, но как её решить?

```
C:\Users\User>pip install scrapy
Collecting scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-17.9.0.tar.bz2
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting queuelib (from scrapy)
  Using cached queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting parsel>=1.1 (from scrapy)
  Using cached parsel-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.0.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.1.4 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Installing collected packages: Twisted, cssselect, queuelib, parsel, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [UnicodeDecodeError при pip-установке библиотеки geopandas на Python 3.6 на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758039/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Помогла установка через miniconda : `https://conda.io/miniconda.html`
После установки ввести в командную строку `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`